# Why A Sum Related To The Harmonic Series Diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

When I recently read about the power rule for infinite sums, I thought that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$$ would converge, as it is akin to a $p$-series, but with an (admittedly nonconstant) $p=1+\frac{1}{n} \ge 1$, and so is strictly less than the harmonic series. However, when I ask WolframAlpha for an evaluation, it claims that the sum diverges by the comparison test. I could accept this, but for the fact that I am not aware of a particular sum strictly lesser than my above sum that diverges. What might be a sum that fulfills that criterion?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1752151/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2266680/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054911/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673312/42969.

Comment: Oh. My question is not original. That’s disappointing. Oh well. What can you do?

Comment: We have $n^{1/n}\le 2$, so $\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n\le\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1{nn^{1/n}}$. And there you have a series that is strictly less than your series. Both diverge.